# compare all couples of numeric columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following csv file:

> ```
> C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7
> 0,1,1,1,1,1,1
> 1,1,1,1,1,1,1
> 0,1,1,1,0,0,1
> 0,1,0,1,0,0,1
> 0,1,1,1,1,1,1
> 1,1,1,1,1,1,1
> ```

I would like to create a dataframe comparing columns pairs.
I would like to count the number of times each pair of column share the value of 1. So, for the data showed at the beginning of the question, I would like to generate the following dataframe:

```
   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7
C1
C2
C3
C4
C5
C6
C7
```

**[C1,C1]** will contain the number of times C1 is equal to 1:

> awk -F',' '$1==1' f.csv | wc -l

**[C1,C2]** will contain the number of times C1 is equal to C2 and equal to 1.

> awk -F',' '$1==1 && $1==$2' f.csv | wc -l

Is there any easier way to calculate this? Maybe using `pandas`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the data frame contains only 1 and 0, you can use matrix multiplication [dot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv("/path/to/csvfile")

df.T.dot(df)
```

[image]

Comment: I agree with them ^^^

Comment: @piRSquared I know you know better than this. **